# Swagger tries to load resources on HTTPS and fails

Tags: docker, docker-compose, swagger, swagger-ui

I have a dockerized API that includes swagger. It runs nicely locally. I also runsnicely in a local docker container. But when deployed to a remote server: the container runs well on the server over **HTTP**, the API is accessible and responsive, but when I hit the swagger route, I get the index page, and it tries loading all the resources (js, css, images) over **HTTPS** for some reason - and they all fail, since my remote server does not have HTTP configured.

Why is that page trying to load resources over HTTPS? And why does it work in a local container and not on the remote server? Is this something I need to fix on the server, or something in my swagger config?

Comment: I just looked at the source of the `index.html` page for swagger - all resources are loaded with `href="./resourcename"` - so HTTPS is not forces in the source - something else is causing it.

Environment: Node LTS (14.3), Fastify, Swagger 2.0 loaded through fastify-swagger plugin, Docker 20.*.

Comment: remote server may have an nginx/apache rule to redirect all HTTP to HTTPs. Try inconginto, sometimes some browser plugins do this too.

Comment: Is there something like apache/nginx/traefik sitting in front of the API? Similar to Rakesh' suggestion, they can add headers that instruct an app to make things look https to the outside world, in case they are terminating the TLS connection for the backend.

Comment: Thanks for the comments - as you might have surmised, I have no control of that server - I'll check. But thanks for putting me on the right track!